# How I can read "Record" results of MMA Fight?

Tags: mixed-martial-arts

Looking at the Wikipedia article for [Mirko Filipović](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirko_Filipovi%C4%87), his "[Mixed martial arts record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirko_Cro_Cop#Mixed_martial_arts_record)" is shown as a table with a "Record" column.

How do I interpret this column?

Example #1(without brackets):

```
23–6–2
```

Example #2(with brackets):

```
34–11–2 (1)
```

I think it means:

`1st Round Points`-`2nd Round Points`-`3th Round Points`( `?` )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The record is Mirko Filipović's cumulative record as of each fight. It is not a recording of what happened in that particular fight.

The breakdown is: 
Wins - Losses - Draws (No contests)

Taking your example 2 as a concrete example:
34–11–2 (1)

- 34 wins
- 11 losses
- 2 draws
- 1 no contest (fight stop by officials without a winner)